# Facebook type friend request sent and friend request accept database query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am learning database and new to sql so please help me out!

I created table for facebook style application to send and accept friend request as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `friends`
(
    `friend_one` INT(11) ,
    `friend_two` INT(11) ,
    `status` ENUM('0','1','2'),

    PRIMARY KEY (`friend_one`,`friend_two`),
    FOREIGN KEY (friend_one) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (friend_two) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

- `status = 0` indicates friend request sent and
- `status = 1` indicates request accepted

When friend confirmed the friend request, I will update the status 0 to 1

so I used following query

```
UPDATE friends
SET status = "1"
WHERE 
    (friend_one = "$user_id" OR friend_two = "$user_id") 
    AND 
    (friend_one = "$friend_id" OR friend_two = "$friend_id");
```

but I didn't get answer can you please help me out!!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what did you not get here?